# Frequently logged out of Cerberus Network on PC

Tags: mass-effect-2, me2-cerberus-network

I have the Steam version of ME2 and am able to log into the Cerberus Network without issue.  However, whenever I start up the game the "Cerberus laptop" spins for a few seconds and then says:

> Communication with the Mass Effect 2 server was interrupted or has timed out

After this I have to log in again, which works perfectly so I don't think it's actually a communication issue.  It's getting pretty annoying to have to do this every time I play — is there any way to fix it so I'll just stay signed in?

Comment: I think this is a bug on the end of the developers. It is probably a leftover error from when they actually had servers that supported new features (shortly after it came out.)  Given that it doesn't prevent gameplay, I doubt it will ever be fixed.  I have the same problem.